# React testing: How can I reach the instance of a connected (redux) component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, redux

I want to be able to test methods of a component that is being exported as a connected component, so I need to reach the instance of that component.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

I'm having trouble reaching that instance.

Comment: export the unconnected component as well? http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html#connected-components

Comment: @azium seems lie the only way, thank you azium I'm going with that.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I take is to create unit tests for `MyComponent`, `mapStateToProps`, and `mapDispatchToProps`. It looks like unit tests for `MyComponent` would accomplish what you're looking to do.

Integration tests with Redux are helpful for determining if any future upgrade breaks functionality you're depending on, but you don't need to fully boot your app with Redux to determine if the methods of your component are working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option for you would be to export the unconnected component, and create tests where you pass the props that you would get from the store (Basically bypassing `mapStateToProps`).

Another option is to create a test for the connected component. In this case, you need to wrap it in a `Provider`, and give it an initial state, so that it gets the information from the store itself. One example of a helper that does that with `jest` would be:

```
import React from 'react'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store'

const fullRender = (jsx, state = {}) => {
  const store = configureMockStore([](state)
  const component = renderer.create(
    <Provider store={store}>
      {jsx}
    </Provider>
  )

  return { store, component }
}
export default fullRender
```

this can be extended to use a more realistic setup, like including middleware in the state (such as *thunk*) or also taking routing into account. Then you can build your test like this (again using `jest`):

```
import React from 'react'
import { fullRender } from '../../test'
import Header from './Header'

describe('components', () => {
  let state = { a: { b: 3 } }
  describe('Header', () => {
    it('renders correctly', () => {
      const { component } = fullRender(<Header />, state)
      expect(component.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot()
    })
  })
})
```

you can store a "snapshot" of your test as a fixture, and feed it to your test as well.

Comment: Thanks Mario, but this is testing the render of the component, not reaching the instance of it.

Lets  say I need to test something like :

const componentInstance = <---

const methodReturnValue =  componentInstance.method();
expect(methodReturnValue).to.be.true;

Comment: mhm if you want to have a component where you can manually run its methods maybe you could mount it with `enzyme`, although I'm not sure if that is thought as a good practice